# Fill a grid in RAD studio firemonkey

Tags: web-services, grid, firemonkey, fill

I am new to RAD studio XE7 and firemonkey.
I am developing an android application using firemonkey.
I don't know how to fill a `grid` or a `stringgrid` in android of RAD studio.

I am fetching all data from a webservice (REST), so I cannot assign a `dataset` to a `grid` directly.

How can I fill the `grid` with the webserivce data?
Or can fill `grid` runtime?

Please help me to find out this solution.

Answer (score 0):

TStringGrid is simple, just use the Cells array to write and read data

```
StringGrid1.Cells[0,1] := 'Hello World';
ShowMessage(StringGrid1.Cells[0,2]);
```

For TGrid you need to hook OnGetValue and OnSetValue events. Since these are called repeatedly as the grid is scrolled you may want to cache your data locally. The following is from my site at http://monkeystyler.com/guide/TGrid

### Setting and Getting Cell Data

TGrid does not store any data internally. You can set a cells data and read it back, but each grid only creates the minimum number of cells it needs to display them given the current control size and row height. When a grid is scrolled cells will be recycled and you will need to set new data into those recycled cells.

TGrid actually fetches data on demand through the OnGetValue event whenever it needs to update the display of a cell. OnGetValue passes in the row and column of the cell whose data it needs and expects a TValue record to be returned containing the data.

TValue, declared in the System.RTTI unit, is a record which can store any type of data, similar to a Variant, except that it is type-safe and trying to read data of the wrong type will result in an access violation. Since TValue is a record there is no need to ‘free’ it.

A TValue uses generics to specify the data type to read or write. The example below shows an example of setting data for each of the built in cell types,

```
procedure TForm1.Grid1GetValue(Sender: TObject; const Col, Row: Integer;
  var Value: TValue);
begin
  if Col = 0 then
    //TTextCell
    Value := TValue.From<String>(IntToStr(Row))
  else if Col = 1 then
    //TCheckCell
    Value := TValue.From<Boolean>((Row mod 2) = 0)
  else if Col = 2 then
    //TProgressCell
    Value := TValue.From<Single>(Row)
  else if Col = 3 then
    //TPopupColumn
    //  - doesn't accept data
  else if Col = 4 then
    //TImageColumn
    Value := TValue.From<TBitmap>(ImageControl1.Bitmap);
    //Or Value := TValue.From<String>('C:/Pictures/Kitten.png');
end;
```

The grid passes the TValue to the cell control’s SetData method (introduced by TControl) so the type of data to pass in will depend on what that method accepts. In addition to the ‘correct’ type (eg. a single for a TProgressBar) many SetData methods will parse out a string value such as the TImageControl example above taking a filename as a string.

### OnSetValue

When data in a cell changes the OnSetValue event is called, again with the column and row and a TValue containing the data. Again the example shows how to accept data for all the built in column types.

```
procedure TForm1.Grid1SetValue(Sender: TObject;const Col, Row: Integer;var Value: TValue);
var AString: String;
  ABoolean: Boolean;
  ASingle: Single;
begin
  if Col = 0 then
    //TTextCell
    AString := Value.AsType<String>
  else if Col = 1 then
    //TCheckCell
    ABoolean := Value.AsType<Boolean>
  else if Col = 2 then
    //TProgressCell
    ASingle := Value.AsType<Single>
  else if Col = 3 then
    //TPopupColumn
    //  - doesn't send data
  else if Col = 4 then
    //TImageColumn
    //  - doesn't send data
  ;
end;
```

And just to reiterate, because TValue is type checked it’s only possible to extract the data type it contains. If you wanted your progress cell’s value as a string,

```
AString := Value.As<string>;
```

will give an access violation. Instead you’ll have to extract the data as a floating point number and use, for example, FloatToStr (SysUtils) to do the conversion.